# A way to stop websites from detecting that you're using an adblocker

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, adblock, greasemonkey

Many sites are detecting that we're using an adblocker and making our browsing experience worst by either not displaying the content that we want to see or show us even more ads that the adblocker isn't able to block. In worst cases, they throw some sort of malware at our browsing session and infect our computers if we're not careful.

We want a way to stop websites from finding out that we're using an adblocker.

Comment: If a site blocks an adblocker, does it make this solution an adblocker-blocker-blocker?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy, no its an anti ad blocker blocker.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully done this using greasemonkey add-on and firefox. Steps are to subscribe to
aaklist found here: https://github.com/reek/anti-adblock-killer/ for adblockplus or download greasemonkey addon and install this script.

The adblock filter did not really work for the site I wanted to stop detecting adblock  but the greasemonkey script did.